# Why am I getting "Error: No key set vapidDetails.publicKey"?

Tags: node.js, angular, server, push-notification, progressive-web-apps

I'm trying to run a 'node.js' server for push notification. But I received an error instead. This was picked up on a tutorial for adding push notification using SwPush to PWA on Angular.

Do I need to place the Public key somewhere?? I had generated public and private keys using "web-push generate-vapid-keys".

**Server.js script:**

```
    // server.js
require('dotenv').config({ path: 'variables.env' });

const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors')
const webPush = require('web-push');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();

app.use(cors());

app.use(bodyParser.json());

const publicVapidKey = process.env.PUBLIC_VAPID_KEY;
const privateVapidKey = process.env.PRIVATE_VAPID_KEY;

webPush.setVapidDetails('mailto:test@example.com', publicVapidKey, privateVapidKey);

app.post('/notifications', (req, res) => {
  const subscription = req.body.notification;

  console.log(`Subscription received`);

  res.status(201).json({});

  const payload = JSON.stringify({
    notification: {
      title: 'Notifications are cool',
      body: 'Know how to send notifications through Angular with this article!',
      icon: 'https://www.shareicon.net/data/256x256/2015/10/02/110808_blog_512x512.png',
      vibrate: [100, 50, 100],
      data: {
        url: 'https://medium.com/@arjenbrandenburgh/angulars-pwa-swpush-and-swupdate-15a7e5c154ac'
      }
    }
  });

  webPush.sendNotification(subscription, payload)
    .catch(error => console.error(error));
});

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 5000);
const server = app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
    console.log(`Express running → PORT ${server.address().port}`);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In   your line 1:

```
require('dotenv').config({ path: 'variables.env' });
```

The code above fetches your information from a file named **variables.env**  which you didn't create;
So to fulfill that, create a file with the  name **variables.env** and put all your environmental variables there

**OR**

In order to make it require your information from a **.env** file  directly, change the code in line 1 to:

```
require('dotenv').config();
```